# Vaadin Front-end and Token/Cookie

Tags: java, cookies, token, vaadin

I'm using nodeJS in the back-end environment and most of APIs are ready. I want to use Vaading in the front-end, because of the [Java Spreadsheet component](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-spreadsheet). I have looked at the Bakery example and designed a login page which sends the user credentials to my back-end API. This is the code for sending the POST request to the server.

```
public void submit(String username, String password) throws IOException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("username", username);
        json.put("password", password);


        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        try {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
            HttpResponse response;

            StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(params);
            response = httpClient.execute(request);
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                System.out.println("Okey!");
                // The response contains token. How can I store this token?
                // Also, How can I use the stored token for future Authentication:Bearer?
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        finally {
            httpClient.close();
        }
    }
```

I would like to store the response's token in somewhere(I can store it in the cookie object in React. However, I'm not familiar with this language) and fetch the token from this storage(cookie possibly, *how to implement Cookie in Java web?*) every time I make a request.

Comment: Still a valid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Vaadin do you use? If you are using **Vaadin >= 10**: How about using the session?

You could save the token in the VaadinSession and read it from there on every request.

I created a minimum example where (on button click) I check if a token is already saved in the session. If yes it is printed in a notification. If not it is saved into the session. The code looks like:

```
@Route("")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
        Button button = new Button("Click me", event -> {
            Object token = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("token");
            if (token == null) {
                Notification.show("No token found in session. Now storing token = 123456");
                VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("token", "123456");
            } else {
                Notification.show("Found token in session: " + token.toString());
            }
        });
        add(button);
    }
}
```

The result looks like:

[image]

(button was clicked three times)

**Update**: The same can be used in **Vaadin 8** where the code of a minimum example then looks like:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        Button button = new Button("Click me", event -> {
            Object token = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("token");
            if (token == null) {
                Notification.show("No token found in session. Now storing token = 123456");
                VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("token", "123456");
            } else {
                Notification.show("Found token in session: " + token.toString());
            }
        });

        layout.addComponents(button);

        setContent(layout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using Vaadin8 or something. I upgraded it to 10.0.11. Your code is working

Comment: Sorry for mentioning Vaadin 10 when you said that you mainly use Vaadin in favour of the Spreadsheet component (which is not compatible with Vaadin 10+ - I didn't know that before). The good thing is that the described code also works with Vaadin 8 (`VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("token");` and `VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("token", "123456");`). I will update my answer here.